# Remove li if li text is not found in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an unordered list:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".AirConditioning">Air Conditioning</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Filters">Filters</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Heating">Heating</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Holidays">Holidays</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".HVAC/RTips">HVAC/R Tips</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".IAQ">IAQ</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".LaborShortage">Labor Shortage</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is an array:

```
["Air Conditioning", "Filters"]
```

**What I am trying to do is match array "C" against the text of each li and hide any li's that have text that doesn't match a string in the array. In this case, only "Air Conditioning" and "Filters" should remain in the resulting unordered list.**

**jQuery Code**

This code essentially compares 2 arrays to create a differential array(the one I displayed above. But, I'm stuck as to how to evaluate the li text and compare to the differential array and hide any non-matches.

```
$(function() {

    // Arrays to compare to
    arrayOne = ["Air Conditioning", "Filters", "Heating", "Holidays", "HVAC/R Tips", "IAQ", "Labor Shortage", "Products"];
    arrayTwo = ["Heating", "Holidays", "HVAC/R Tips", "IAQ", "Labor Shortage", "Products"];

    // Create differential array
    var A = arrayOne,
        B = arrayTwo,
        C = [];

    $.each(A, function(i, e) {
        if ($.inArray(e, B) == -1) C.push(e);
    });

    // Log Differential Array
    console.log(C);

    // C = ["Air Conditioning", "Filters"]

});
```

[I created a Fiddle if that is helpful.](https://jsfiddle.net/coryspi/6poc1988/)

Thanks!

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I am trying to do is match an array against the text of each li and hide any li's that have text that doesn't match a string in the array.

In order to achieve this you can [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the li and return only the li with a text content included (i.e.: [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) + [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) in the **C** array.

The filter is:

```
$('.dropdown-menu li').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    return C.indexOf(ele.textContent) == -1;
}).hide();
```

```js
var arrayOne = ["Air Conditioning", "Filters", "Heating", "Holidays", "HVAC/R Tips", "IAQ", "Labor Shortage", "Products"];
var arrayTwo = ["Heating", "Holidays", "HVAC/R Tips", "IAQ", "Labor Shortage", "Products"];

// Compare all category array with current tab array and get string difference
var A = arrayOne,
        B = arrayTwo,
        C = [];

$.each(A, function(i, e) {
    if ($.inArray(e, B) == -1) C.push(e);
});


$('.dropdown-menu li').filter(function(idx, ele) {
    return C.indexOf(ele.textContent) == -1;
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".AirConditioning">Air Conditioning</a></li>
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Filters">Filters</a></li>
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Heating">Heating</a></li>
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Holidays">Holidays</a></li>
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".HVAC/RTips">HVAC/R Tips</a></li>
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".IAQ">IAQ</a></li>
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".LaborShortage">Labor Shortage</a></li>
    <li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi gaetanoM, thanks for this. I did notice that this filter function hides the items that were in the "c" array. I'm looking to hide all of the items not in the "c" array. In other words, I should see "Air Conditioning" and "Filters" in my unordered list.

Comment: I added this clarification to the original question.

Comment: @dentalhero Answer and snippet updated. Instead of C.indexOf(ele.textContent) != -1; you need C.indexOf(ele.textContent) == -1;

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    // loop through every link
    // get the text of the link
    // compare it
    // hide those that don't match (hide their parent element, that is: the li element containeing the link)
    $('li a').each(function(i, e) {
        const linkText = e.innerHTML;

      if($.inArray(linkText, C) == -1) {
        $(e).parent().hide()
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var  arrayOne = ["Air Conditioning", "Filters", "Heating", "Holidays", "HVAC/R Tips", "IAQ", "Labor Shortage", "Products"];
  var C=[];

$(".dropdown-menu .filterMenu a").each(function(key,value){
   if ($.inArray($(value).text(), arrayOne ) == -1){
       C.push($(value).text());
       $(value).parent().remove()

   }
});
console.log(C);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".AirConditioning">Air Conditioning</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Filters">Filters</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Heating">Heating</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Holidays">Holidays</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".HVAC/RTips">HVAC/R Tips</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".IAQ">IAQ</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".LaborShortage">Labor3 Shortage</a></li>
<li class="filterMenu"><a href="#" data-path=".Products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```